# How to put BCC in Devise 3.0.0 for Rails 3.2.9?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, bcc

I'm have already tried to rewrite the headers_for, but it's still not working.
Here goes my code:
app/mailers/devise_notifier.rb:

```
class DeviseNotifier < Devise::Mailer    
  def headers_for(action, opts)
    super.merge!({bcc: 'my@mail.com'})
  end
end
```

app/config/initializers/devise.rb:

```
Devise.setup do |config|
  config.mailer = "DeviseNotifier"
  ...
end
```

Comment: Could you open up the question also on the text field, not only on title. I think also more details about the situation are needed.

Comment: Had an answer but I think it may have been more complicated than necessary. The first question is: did you tell devise to use your custom mailer in `config/initializers/devise.rb` with `config.mailer = "DeviseNotifier"`?

Comment: Yes, @gregates :

`Devise.setup do |config|
  config.mailer_sender = "my@email.com.br"
  config.mailer = "DeviseNotifier"
  ...
end`

Answer (score 1):

`headers_for` helper already merges `opts` with the default headers. I'd try overwriting `send_devise_notification` on your user model (or whatever the devise resource is).

```
def send_devise_notification(notification, opts={})
  opts.merge!({bcc: 'my@mail.com'})
  devise_mailer.send(notification, opts).deliver
end
```

or for devise 3.1 or later:

```
def send_devise_notification(notification, *args)
  opts = args.extract_options!
  args.push(opts.merge({bcc: 'my@mail.com'}))
  devise_mailer.send(notification, self, *args).deliver
end
```

Comment: I've tried this and got this error:
_"ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (3 for 2)"_

I found [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/6b3b0c5e8c57253d3d178def678ccc26e66cd630/lib/devise/models/authenticatable.rb) that the function `send_devise_notification` can be rewritable. But the arguments are: `(notification, *args)`.
So I couldn't modify the `opts`

Comment: That's true on devise 3.1, but I thought you were using 3.0? On 3.0, it's `send_devise_notification(notification, opts={})`

Comment: Oops, I see what happened -- I originally had a version that would work in 3.1, and when I tried to change it for your version, I left out one crucial change.

Comment: I've tried everything that you said (even updated to devise 3.1.0), but still not working. Just to be sure that I'm on the right way, I put **CC** instead of **BCC** and it worked.

Comment: do you have still any other try?